# Recursively sort levels within a multidimensional array of unknown depth by a column while preserving keys

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, usort

To sort an existing multidimensional array I tried to use usort, but it wont bring me any result. As I can not use nested sets or something like this because of the given structure, I have to sort it:

My array:

```
[
    2 => [
        'position' => 0,
        'children' => [
            3 => ['position' => "375"],
            5 => ['position' => "44"],
            6 => ['position' => "567"],
            9 => [
                'position' =>  "12",
                'children' => [
                    74 => ['position' => "2"],
                    76 => ['position' => "3"],
                    77 => ['position' => "1"],
                ]
            ],
            62 => ['position' => "34"],
            63 => ['position' => "11"],
            66 => ['position' => "114"],
            74 => ['position' => "912"],
            76 => ['position' => "4564"],
        ]
    ]
]
```

I would like to sort every level by its node named "children". Recursion should be no problem. It can be a variable structure where the node "children" can exist ... or not :)

Desired result after sorting by `position` column values:

```
[
    2 => [
        'position' => 0,
        'children' => [
            63 => ['position' => "11"],
            9 => [
                'position' =>  "12",
                'children' => [
                    77 => ['position' => "1"],
                    74 => ['position' => "2"],
                    76 => ['position' => "3"],
                ]
            ],
            62 => ['position' => "34"],
            5 => ['position' => "44"],
            66 => ['position' => "114"],
            3 => ['position' => "375"],
            6 => ['position' => "567"],
            74 => ['position' => "912"],
            76 => ['position' => "4564"],
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried the following code unsuccessfully:

```
public function recur($data){
        // ...
        foreach($data as $key=>$value){
            if (array_key_exists('children', $value)) {
            usort($value, function ($a, $b): int {
                if ($a['position'] === $b['position']) {
                // ....
                }
                return $a['position'] <=> $b['position'];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not return any data, so we must assume that your intention is to modify by reference.  To implement modification by reference in your recursive method, use the `&` symbol in the method's argument signature and the `$value` variable of the `foreach()`.

The key-preserving sort on the `position` column data needs to be done outside of the loop to access the data properly.

After sorting the current row, you can recursively iterate any subset that contains `children` data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uKi1A))

```
function recur(&$data): void
{
    uasort($data, fn($a, $b) => $a['position'] <=> $b['position']);
    foreach($data as &$value){
        if (isset($value['children'])) {
            recur($value['children']);
        }
    }
}
recur($array);
var_export($array);
```

Comment: First, of all, thank you for the time and work you invested to answer my question! 
I accept your solution as brilliant and simple at once. Thank you.

It don't work < php 7.4 but for the reason of DDEV this is not a real prob. thanks for this solution

Comment: [this works](https://3v4l.org/1jW4N) all the way down to PHP7.0 which was when the spaceship operator was born.